# Product Collection Methods: addFieldToSelect() vs. addAttributeSelect()

Tags: magento2, collection, magento2.4, product-collection

What is the difference between `->addFieldToSelect('name')` and `->addAttributeToSelect('name')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
addAttributeToSelect() is used to select EAV collections. (like https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/attributes.html#customer-eav-attribute)
addFieldToSelect() is used to select Non-EAV collections.
```

Comment: What would be non-EAV collections?

Comment: Any flat tables are non-eav collections. Like if you create a custom table for your custom module then you can say that is flat table/non-eav collections.